# How to use OpenRecordSet?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to use `OpenRecordSet`.

The parameter is the query:

```
Select * FROM Batiments WHERE Type = "2";
```

which works perfectly if I write it as a query.

However with `OpenRecordSet` I get this error:

```
Object variable or With block variable not set
```

I don't understand what is wrong and from all tutorial of similar case I see, my syntax should be correct.

Here is the full code:

```
temp = "Select * FROM Batiments WHERE Type = " & Chr(34) & txtNouveauBatiment.Value & Chr(34) & ";"
        rstBatiment.OpenRecordset tmp

        If (rstBatiment.EOF) Then
            Set dbs = CurrentDb
            Set rstBatiment = dbs.OpenRecordset("Batiments")

            rstBatiment.AddNew
            rstBatiment!Type = txtNouveauBatiment.Value
            rstBatiment.Update

            Refresh
        End If
```

Comment: Please share the full code (vba). The SQL part is probably less relevant.

Comment: You got to show your code!

Comment: It's often something silly like forgetting to do `set db = CurrentDb` or whatever. It probably has nothing to do with your SQL. Look at the rest of your code.

Comment: added the code!!

Comment: in  vba,  you  must change  double quote  to  single quote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.OpenRecordset` method on the recordset object is not intended to open a new recordset, but rather to open a filtered recordset (using the `.Filter` property) based on an open recordset.

If you want to open a new recordset, you need to use `CurrentDb.OpenRecordset`:

```
temp = "Select * FROM Batiments WHERE [Type] = " & Chr(34) & txtNouveauBatiment.Value & Chr(34) & ";"
Set dbs = CurrentDb
Set rstBatiment = dbs.OpenRecordset(temp)

If (rstBatiment.EOF) Then
    Set rstBatiment = dbs.OpenRecordset("Batiments")
    rstBatiment.AddNew
    rstBatiment!Type = txtNouveauBatiment.Value
    rstBatiment.Update
    Refresh
End If
```

Note that I don't really get the `Refresh` line. If you're refreshing a form, it's usual to specify you're executing a method on the current form object, e.g. `Me.Refresh`.

Also note that `Type` is one of the [reserved words](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-e33eb3a9-8baa-4335-9f57-da237c63eabe) in Access SQL, thus needs to be bracketed

Comment: thx!! I was playing with it and got the same result, however now I have another problem: The Microsoft Access database engine cannot find the input table or query ". Make sure it exists and that its name is spellect correctly. So I think it complains about the ", but I don't understand why? My request, from debugger is : "Select * FROM Batiments WHERE Type = "ewr";"

Comment: See the current edit for a short explanation and solution (at least I think that's the issue)

Comment: You are actually sure your table/queryname is correct (you have a table named `Batiments`)?

Comment: yes, to ensure I wasn't mispelling, I added a query, pasted the SQL code and then tested results. it does work

Comment: if I would add it on a share site, would you be interested in checking it? It's quite simple I'm in the early stages

Comment: I will be on for about 10 minutes, but I'll check it if you hurry ;)

Comment: to test it's simple, just open frmBatiments -> over button ajouter fill something, this is the Type, then click "Ajouter" you will then be brought into the code

Comment: The code in the file you've shared isn't equal to the code I've suggested. The line `Set rstBatiment = dbs.OpenRecordset(tmp)` is wrong, since the variable is named `temp`, not `tmp`. That's likely the cause of the error. You can avoid these kinds of errors by adding `Option Explicit` at the top of your module.

Comment: ho wow!! thanks a lot!! This is the first time I code in VBA, I didn't even though I could use a variable that wasn't declared (use to C#, C++... etc). So I will accept your answer as good one, I probably mixed name at one point!! Thanks for all your help and have good holidays!! I'll definitely use Option Explicit

Comment: Note that the standard editor has the _require variable declaration_ option under _Options_ -> _editor_. This adds `Option Explicit` to all new modules, so you don't have to think about it.